# Preventing session timeout via ssh/bash/screen/etc?

Tags: bash, ssh, display, putty, timeout

On this particular server, it seems that it's configured somehow to close a session if there is no activity after a few minutes.  I'm looking for a good way to prevent it from timing out via my setup of sshing to a primary server using PuTTY for which I have 'sending of null packets to keep session active set to 10 which keeps the session up without issue.  I then run gnu screen on the host and ssh out to other machines.  It is from these latter machines that I become disconnected.  I have tried a few ssh options in my client but I don't think any of them seem to have worked.  Whatever mechanism PuTTY uses does seem to work however.

Any ideas are appreciated.  I prefer to keep one PuTTY window open than fooling around with multiple windows on my desktop.  I'm also not interested in PuTTY Connection Manager either as it is buggy and very slow.

Comment: For reference, this is the specific message: timed out waiting for input: auto-logout

Comment: I think I found it.  It is the $TMOUT variable being set in /etc/profile.  I overrode it in ~/.bash_profile and it looks like it might be working.

Comment: Good find. You should post it as an answer and accept it (it will let you after 24 hours) in order to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I have my screen session include the local clock in the status bar.  That updates once a second, which works as a keep-alive.

My status bar in .screenrc looks like:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%H %{= mK}%-Lw%{= KW}%50>%n%f* %t%{= mK}%+Lw%< %{= kG}%-=%D %d %M %Y %c:%s%{-}'
```

Comment: Well that will only prevent my putty connection to the first machine from timing out which already doesn't timeout.  I don't nest screens so I need this to work purely on the ssh/bash level.